# python3.3 matplotlib cannot import name _tkagg

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

The default backend for my matplotlib is 'agg'. I read on stackoverflow ([How can I set the 'backend' in matplotlib in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-to-set-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python)) that in order to display graphics I need to use TkAgg, WX, QTAgg, or QT4Agg. I tried using all 4 (mpl.use('TkAgg') etc) and matplotlib cannot find any of them (I cannot use QTAgg or QT4Agg because it is not compatible with python3 according to matplotlib). I'm not sure what is wrong since when I go to /usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/, tkagg.py and backend_tkagg.py are both there. These errors all apply to wx also.

I use python3.3 on Quantal if that has any relevance.

Comment: what about `_tkagg.so`?

Comment: That's why it cannot import it.

Comment: how did you install mpl, and what OS are you using?

Comment: Where can I get _tkagg.so?

Comment: I installed mpl from source and I'm using Ubuntu Quantal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was getting the same error on Fedora 18. I installed the matplotib package for Python 3 from the repository.

Installing the package `python3-matplotlib-tk` got rid of this error for me on Fedora.

On Ubuntu, install the `tk-dev` package, and install matplotlib again: `python3 setup.py build` and `python3 setup.py install`.

However, I soon ran into this one on Fedora: [Python 3 and matplotlib lissue on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717119/python-3-and-matplotlib-lissue)

Comment: You may want to move the second part of your answer to a new question.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? I typed 'sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib-tk' into the terminal but it says that it is unable to locate the packagee.

Comment: @user2163653 Added to my answer. Install tk-dev and rebuild and reinstall should help.