# Python 3 and matplotlib lissue on Linux

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.3

I have been facing a couple of issues in using matplotlib with Python 3. After getting rid of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708226/python3-3-matplotlib-cannot-import-name-tkagg) one, I ran into a new one. When I tried to execute the [histogram demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/histogram_demo.html), I get this [traceback](http://pastebin.ca/2345456).

Does anyone have an idea? My matplotlib version is: python3-matplotlib-1.2.0-8.fc18.x86_64 (i.e. 1.2 on Fedora 18).

Bugs filed:

1. [Fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=929383)
2. [Matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1873)

Comment: @eryksun It says: font_manager attribute not found o_O.

Comment: Okay, my bad. It reports True.

Comment: Thanks @eryksun. I went ahead and set it to False in /usr/lib/* itself. And it worked. You reckon I should report this as a bug upstream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the top of the [histogram_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/histogram_demo.html), just before `import numpy`:

```
from matplotlib import font_manager
font_manager.USE_FONTCONFIG = False
```

Or modify [font_manager.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v1.2.0/lib/matplotlib/font_manager.py#L65) to change the value permanently.

As far as bug reports go, I'd report the `USE_FONTCONFIG = True` setting to the Fedora package manager. The `subprocess` output decoding issue (or regex pattern issue) in Python 3.x should be reported upstream to the [matplotlib project](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib).

Comment: Adding the two lines in the histogram_demo.py file doesn't work, because USE_FONTCONFIG is set to True in font_manager.py, when its imported by backend_agg.py. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Amit: Sorry, I guess you're right. I only use matplotlib in 2.x. When I do `import matplotlib` it doesn't load the `font_manager` module. I have to import `matplotlib.pyplot` for that to happen.