# Matplotlib does not display figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using python 3 in Ubuntu 13.04.

This simple example runs without errors, but it doesn't display any plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [4,3,2,1]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I have tried to change the backend from Agg to TkAgg but I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "test2.py", line 1, in
>
> ```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> ```
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line> 98, in
>
> ```
> _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
> ```
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/**init**.py", line 28, in pylab_setup
>
> ```
> globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
> ```
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",line 11, in
>
> ```
> import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
> ```
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py",line 2, in
>
> ```
> from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
> ```
>
> ImportError: cannot import name _tkagg

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

### EDIT:

I have found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708226/python3-3-matplotlib-cannot-import-name-tkagg).
In case someone has the same problem, the solution is to install the tk-dev package on ubuntu, and then reinstall matplotlib.
In my case:

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev
sudo pip3 uninstall matplotlib
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

Comment: This isn't much help, but your example works fine for me with Ubuntu 13.10 under python2 and python3.  This was with whatever the default backend is; I don't know how to change it.  I notice a /usr/local/lib/python3.2 in your backtrace---are you using a matplotlib library you've compiled yourself?

Comment: @Rory Yorke: I've installed it using pip3. I read somewhere that the backend might be a problem, so I changed it in the [matplotlibrc file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#customizing-matplotlib). But now that I installed the right dependencies to use tk as a backend (see my edit), it is working. :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into some similar issues with this. It's better to install matplotlib using `apt-get` instead of `pip`

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

- [via some discussion](http://bayespy.org/install.html) <strike>that I can't find anymore (I'll update the post if I come across it again)</strike>

"on Ubuntu (>= 12.10), you may install the dependencies for each package as:"

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3-matplotlib
```

Comment: Wouldn't that install matplotlib on python 2? I am starting out with python, so I've decided to go with python 3.

Comment: you're right! sorry, I had meant to change that. It should just be `python3-matplotlib` Edited now

Comment: that was easy peasy .. it looks like it actually replaced the pip3 packages with native compatible ones. Jammy release