# No module named _backend_gdk

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, spyder

I am using Spyder with python 2.7 and matplotlib on a windows machine.

I am trying to run my script and I am getting the following error:

```
runfile('C:/Python27/Scripts/python-serial-plot.py', wdir=r'C:/Python27/Scripts')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 601, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 66, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Python27/Scripts/python-serial-plot.py", line 8, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_gtkagg.py", line 14, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import gtk, FigureManagerGTK, FigureCanvasGTK,\
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_gtk.py", line 36, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gdk import RendererGDK, FigureCanvasGDK
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_gdk.py", line 33, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends._backend_gdk import pixbuf_get_pixels_array
ImportError: No module named _backend_gdk
```

I went to the directory where the backends are stored and can't see `_backend_gdk`.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: switch the backend for matplotlib

Comment: Check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/4930524/1860929

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your graphics backend to fix this error. In Spyder you need to go to

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Graphics backend`

and select there either `Inline` or `Automatic` there.

Answer (score -1):

You can switch the backend to list all backends:

```
In [5]: import matplotlib

In [6]: matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends
```

Then use `matplotlib.use('some_backend')`  to choose another, I don't use windows so cannot recommend what to use but you can try different ones and see what works best.

The `matplotlib.use('some_backend')` should be before any `import matplotlib.pyplot` etc.. statements

[what is a backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the issue the asker is facing. They know of backends and have imported one, but `matplotlib` is throwing an error anyways.