# Anaconda ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

Here's my python import statements

```
import plotly as py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.tools as plotly_tools
from plotly.graph_objs import *

os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = tempfile.mkdtemp()
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

from IPython.display import HTML
```

It throws and ImportError **`ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`**

I know there is problem with this import statement 
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Try this command if you are using ubuntu:**
`pyqt4` might be missing

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-qt4
```

It worked for me.

Comment: If you're using Amazon Linux (ie. on AWS) or Red Hat Linux, this becomes `sudo yum install python-qt4`

Comment: This also resolves this warning after installing R through Conda on Ubuntu:  ```doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/var/opt/miniconda3/lib/R/modules//R_X11.so':
  libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the `backend` you're using for matplotlib.

It appears you're on the Qt backend. To avoid installing Qt, you can [change it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4930786/786559) to something native to your distribution, such as GTKAgg

Answer (score 0):

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```