# Why am I getting UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using ps, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is not in a `jupyter` notebook so this is not a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365357/when-i-use-matplotlib-in-jupyter-notebook-it-always-raise-matplotlib-is-curren), but my code is:

```
from gluoncv import model_zoo, data, utils
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

...
plt.show()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
/figure.py:445: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using ps, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  % get_backend())
```

I created a repl at https://repl.it/@shamoons/WelloffHarmfulMineral

If it matters, I'm using OS X. What do I need to do to get the image to show?

Comment: The `PS` backend is intended for creating PostScript files, not displaying graphs. That warning is `matplotlib` telling you that your call to `plt.show()` won't do what you think it'll do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matplotlib.use('PS')` and `plt.show()` are mutually exclusive. You need to decide:

- Do you want to show the figure on screen? Solution: Remove the line `matplotlib.use('PS')`.
- Do you want to use the `PS` backend? This seems unlikely, because there is rarely a reason to set the backend to something non-interactive unless working on a server. Anyways, solution: Replace `plt.show()` by `plt.savefig("filname.ps")`.

Comment: I modified the code and removed `matplotlib.use('PS')`. I'm getting the same error

Comment: Probably because you didn't restart the kernel after doing that change.

Comment: I'm not running a notebook. This is `Python` running on my mac, so how would I restart the kernel?

Comment: Ok, how are you running this? Can you create a [mcve]? What is gluoncv?

Comment: I created a repl at https://repl.it/@shamoons/WelloffHarmfulMineral, however I'm running on Mac OS X

Comment: That repl.it link results in different errors for me. Also, on the repl.it server you may indeed not be able to `show()` a figure. So coming back to your local computer, can you set the backend before importing gluoncv, `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg"); import gluoncv....`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest what if i want to show a live plot ? i mean, i'm updating my plot continously, so `savefig` is not a good idea since i have to close/re-open the images lots of time. do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: @Tiendung You cannot use the the PS backend for live plots.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
```

instead of

```
matplotlib.use("PS")
```

when developing on MacOS.

Please note that the import should be before importing `plt`, like this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```