# Why is this Joyplot code on matplotlib showing this error?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ridgeline-plot

I wrote a simple code to start off with Joyplots on Matplotlib. Here's the entire code:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt import joypy

random.seed(4554)

randomlist = random.sample(range(100,10000),1000) 
randomyear = np.linspace(1018,2018,num=1001)
 
df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(randomyear,randomlist)),columns=['Year','Values'])

fig, axes = joypy.joyplot(df, by="Year", column="Values",figsize=(5,8))

plt.show()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: `dataset` input should have multiple elements.
```

What does this mean, what am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate multiple records per year; your code generates single record per year.

I've updated your random number generation:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import joypy

random.seed(4554)

randomlist = np.random.rand(1000)
randomyear = list(range(1999, 2019)) * 50

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(randomyear,randomlist)), columns= ['Year','Values'])

fig, axes = joypy.joyplot(df, by="Year", column="Values",figsize=(5,8))
```

Comment: Ah that might explain it. But be that as it may, the new code produces this error - `UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.`
I tried researching this error and I tried using a solution pointed out on Stack itself but it isn't solving anything. What are backend errors?

Comment: I've not come across that error but found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365357/when-i-use-matplotlib-in-jupyter-notebook-it-always-raise-matplotlib-is-curren . If you're running in jupyer try running `%matplotlib inline`.

Comment: I've been staring at that exact post for the past thirty minutes. Doesn't help. It's for Ubuntu and one of the answers just states to remove fig.show() - which in no way helps me see what I've just made. 
Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: Good luck figuring it out :)

Comment: Interesting. I figured out a way to directly save the image using `plt.savefig()` without displaying it and sure enough that works. I'd still want to see the image though. Don't know what's going to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using the following code:

```
fig, axes = joypy.joyplot(data_sub[["AC","B"]], by="AC", column="B")

ValueError: `dataset` input should have multiple elements.
```

I checked my dataframe column "AC". This column was supposed to only include values AC1, AC2 and AC3.

But I noticed that I have

- 100 rows of "AC1"
- 103 rows of "AC2"
- 99 rows of "AC3"
- 1 row of "Other" (this should have been AC3)

I replaced "Other" with "AC3" so that no values in the "AC" column of my dataset appears only once. It fixed my problem.