# UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

how to solve it

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you are trying to do, perhaps a snippet of the code you are using and a complete stack trace of the error? Hard to get the exact solution with only the error text. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37365357/5028532) if you're using jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure." when plotting figure with pyplot on Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656777/userwarning-matplotlib-is-currently-using-agg-which-is-a-non-gui-backend-so)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a different backend if you want to use `plt.show()`. The `Agg` backend can only write plots to files, not show an interactive output.
You set the backend globally by setting the `backend` field in your matplotlibrc file (https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file).

You can also set the backend from within your program. Just have a look at the page linked above.