# Matplotlib is currently using module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend problem

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, python-3.9

I am interested to know how ginput() of matplotlib works?When I run the following simple code

```
axis([-1, 1, -1, 1])
print( "Please click three times")
pts = ginput(3)
```

I get

**:3: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
pts = ginput(3)**

I am using matplotlib 3.3.3 and jupyter notebook with python 3.9.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I use matplotlib in jupyter notebook,it always raise " matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365357/when-i-use-matplotlib-in-jupyter-notebook-it-always-raise-matplotlib-is-curren)

Comment: Thanks , following isn't working for me
```
%pylab inline --------- Not working for me
fig.show() ---------- Not using
%matplotlib inline  --------  not working
```

It worked
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

Comment: Same problem here when running plot in a Jupyterlab notebook. Problem was caused by calling fig.show(), rather than just fig.