# Pycharm - Importing Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've installed Pycharm  and using Anaconda 3 as my interpreter. I cannot import Matplotlib (or Seaborn). When I run 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt' I get the following:--

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_ipython\inputhook.py", line 502, in enable_gui
    gui_hook = guis[gui] KeyError: 'qt5'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 123, in enable_gui
        return real_enable_gui(gui, app)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_ipython\inputhook.py", line 508, in enable_gui
        raise ValueError(e)
    ValueError: Invalid GUI request 'qt5', valid ones are:dict_keys(['osx', 'gtk', 'qt4', 'qt', 'gtk3', 'glut', 'pyglet',
'wx', 'none', 'tk'])
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-eff513f636fd>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2512, in <module>
    install_repl_displayhook()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 165, in install_repl_displayhook
    ip.enable_gui(ipython_gui_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 125, in enable_gui
    raise UsageError("%s" % e)
IPython.core.error.UsageError: Invalid GUI request 'qt5', valid ones are:dict_keys(['osx', 'gtk', 'qt4', 'qt', 'gtk3', 'glut', 'pyglet', 'wx', 'none', 'tk'])
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-can-i-set-the-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python and use qt4

Answer (score 4):

Try running `pip install PyQt5` in the command line (not Python, windows cmd or unix terminal). If this doesn't work - try `conda install PyQt5`. Though this doesn't make sense as matplotlib uses tkinter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your  reply. I get these errors:

> conda install PyQt5   --Fetching package metadata......Conda HTTPError : HTTP Error :Could not find URL:https://conda.anaconda.org/seaborn/win-64


>pip install PyQt5 -- Could not find a version that satisfies the the requirement PyQt5 <from versions:> No matching distributions for for PyQt5

Comment: I corrected the channels for the conda install  , I now get this:


Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current win-64 ch
annels:
  - pyqt5

Close matches found; did you mean one of these?

    pyqt5: pyqt

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda pyqt5

Comment: OK finally managed to install it but I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

I have just stumbled across the same issue and found a way to solve it easily. I could not make it work with Qt5, so I switched the backend to TkAgg.

First of all, and this is very optional, I updated `matplotlib` via `conda update matplotlib`. I did this in order to make sure that I have the backend TkAgg included (however, it has been added in 2014 in conda so...).

Then I changed the backend instruction in the `matplotlibrc` file that is located in `C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\matplotlib-2.0.2-np113py35_0\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\` if you are using Anaconda3.

Check your version of `matplotlib` and `numpy` in Pycharm in Settings -> Project interpreter to make sure that you are modifying the proper file. In my case `matplotlib 2.0.2` and `numpy 1.13`.

Open this `matplotlibrc` file with an editor and change around line 30 the backend instruction (that is originally `Qt5Agg`) to `TkAgg`.

```
#### CONFIGURATION BEGINS HERE

# The default backend; one of GTK GTKAgg GTKCairo GTK3Agg GTK3Cairo
# MacOSX Qt4Agg Qt5Agg TkAgg WX WXAgg Agg Cairo GDK PS PDF SVG
# Template.
# You can also deploy your own backend outside of matplotlib by
# referring to the module name (which must be in the PYTHONPATH) as
# 'module://my_backend'.
backend      : TkAgg  # HERE!!!
```

Then save, restart PyCharm and your `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` should work. You should see that the backend has changed when it starts as it displays:
`Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.`

(Works with Python 3.5.2, Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit))

(Also works with Python 3.6.2, Anaconda 5.5.0 (64-bits))

Answer (score 0):

After having faced this issue many times and never having obtained a working solution from all the available answers, I suggest performing a new `conda` installation from scratch followed by creating a new environment as well. Install `matplotlib` from there and other packages from there as well. I know it's a bit crude but for people (especially non-experts and newcomers) in a hurry this may be the best solution.