# Matplotlib animation not showing

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

When I try this on my computer at home, it works, but not on my computer at work. Here's the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import sys
import multiprocessing


def update_line(num, gen, line):
    data = gen.vals_queue.get()
    data = np.array(data)
    line.set_data(data[..., :num])
    return line,


class Generator(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vals = [[], []]
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.vals_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.vals[0].append(np.random.rand())
            self.vals[1].append(np.random.rand())
            self.vals_queue.put(self.vals)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gen = Generator()
    gen.start()
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')
    plt.xlim(0, 1)
    plt.ylim(0, 1)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.title('test')
    print 11111111111111
    sys.stdout.flush()
    line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, frames=None, fargs=(gen, l),
                                       interval=50, blit=True, repeat=False)
    print 222222222222222222222222
    sys.stdout.flush()
    plt.show()
    print 3333333333333333333333333
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

And the output I see is

```
11111111111111
222222222222222222222222
3333333333333333333333333
```

The application does not exit, it just hangs there, but no figure pops up. I run it from Linux terminal. My version of matplotlib is matplotlib-2.0.0-1.x86_64

Also, I've got this at work (problematic one)

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.46(1)-release
Python 2.7.12
```

Comment: I think we are going to need more information, namely : OS of both computers, python versions in boths, and possibly the shell used to run the python file (for example, IPython will not open another window to display the figure)

Comment: Please see the edit above. I did not run it from iPython, but simply from Linux terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is really hard to reproduce this problem, so I'll try to give some general advises and try to guess the actual root of the problem.

First of all, it is in your best interest to use [virtualenvs](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), if you aren't using them already. You will have a `requirements.txt` file in your project and will freeze the requirements from your home computer (the one that works) into `requirements.txt`, then will create a new `virtualenv` on the computer at work and finally install the requirements. That way you will be sure that you have the same versions of all packages on both computers.

After that you should try and see if it works. If it doesn't please try these things and provide more details:

1. Do you see any errors or warnings when you run it on the computer at work?
2. Can you do very basic plots using `matplotlib`? Like this one:

   `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
   plt.ylabel('some numbers')
   plt.show()`
3. If the example from 2 doesn't work, try to replace `plt.show()` with `plt.savefig('numbers.png')` and see if the figure is successfully saved. If that's the case, then you have some problems with matplotlib's interactivity. If you can't see a file named `numbers.png`, then probably there is something wrong with matplotlib's installation in general, not just the animation part. Or maybe with the installation of some package matplotlib relies on, like Tkinter, for instance.

Instead of going into further hypothetical scenarios, I'll stop here and wait for more details.

p.s. Links you may find useful if there is problem with showing the generated plots/animations in a window:

[How can I set the 'backend' in matplotlib in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-can-i-set-the-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python)

http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the library is exposed to some changes or it is not installed properly. Simply update the library as below,

## For Ubuntu/Debian OS open a terminal and type:

```
                    sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

## For windows open a command line and type:

```
                    python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
                    python -m pip install matplotlib
```

See if that works.

Source: https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html