# Import error for matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I saw similar posts, but the error given when I tried to run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` was different:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jhn545/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/jhn545/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/home/jhn545/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
  File "/home/jhn545/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 26, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "/home/jhn545/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/figureoptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
  File "/home/jhn545/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/formlayout.py", line 56, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
  File "/home/jhn545/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py", line 128, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: libQt5Core.so.5: object file has no loadable segments
```

I'm using miniconda2 and have already tried un-installing and re-installing `matplotlib`

Comment: You could try specifying a different backend than QT? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4930867/3714940

Comment: What platform are you on and what version of python and matplotlib are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @SiHa. The post at [Set Matplotlib Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-can-i-set-the-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python/4930867#4930867) worked perfectly.

One of the answers on that post also gave useful info on how to set the default backend. Simply go to your `matplotlibrc` file (mine was at `miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc`) and change the `backend` variable.