# Python freezes when trying to plot radar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the code suggested by mrbump to create a radar graph (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/16420).

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns # improves plot aesthetics


def _invert(x, limits):
    """inverts a value x on a scale from
    limits[0] to limits[1]"""
    return limits[1] - (x - limits[0])

def _scale_data(data, ranges):
    """scales data[1:] to ranges[0],
    inverts if the scale is reversed"""
    # for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data, ranges):
        assert (y1 <= d <= y2) or (y2 <= d <= y1)

    x1, x2 = ranges[0]
    d = data[0]

    if x1 > x2:
        d = _invert(d, (x1, x2))
        x1, x2 = x2, x1

    sdata = [d]

    for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data[1:], ranges[1:]):
        if y1 > y2:
            d = _invert(d, (y1, y2))
            y1, y2 = y2, y1

        sdata.append((d-y1) / (y2-y1) * (x2 - x1) + x1)

    return sdata

def set_rgrids(self, radii, labels=None, angle=None, fmt=None,
               **kwargs):
    """
    Set the radial locations and labels of the *r* grids.
    The labels will appear at radial distances *radii* at the
    given *angle* in degrees.
    *labels*, if not None, is a ``len(radii)`` list of strings of the
    labels to use at each radius.
    If *labels* is None, the built-in formatter will be used.
    Return value is a list of tuples (*line*, *label*), where
    *line* is :class:`~matplotlib.lines.Line2D` instances and the
    *label* is :class:`~matplotlib.text.Text` instances.
    kwargs are optional text properties for the labels:
    %(Text)s
    ACCEPTS: sequence of floats
    """
    # Make sure we take into account unitized data
    radii = self.convert_xunits(radii)
    radii = np.asarray(radii)
    rmin = radii.min()
    # if rmin <= 0:
    #     raise ValueError('radial grids must be strictly positive')

    self.set_yticks(radii)
    if labels is not None:
        self.set_yticklabels(labels)
    elif fmt is not None:
        self.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter(fmt))
    if angle is None:
        angle = self.get_rlabel_position()
    self.set_rlabel_position(angle)
    for t in self.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
        t.update(kwargs)
    return self.yaxis.get_gridlines(), self.yaxis.get_ticklabels()

class ComplexRadar():
    def __init__(self, fig, variables, ranges,
                 n_ordinate_levels=6):
        angles = np.arange(0, 360, 360./len(variables))

        axes = [fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9],polar=True,
                label = "axes{}".format(i)) 
                for i in range(len(variables))]
        l, text = axes[0].set_thetagrids(angles, 
                                         labels=variables)
        [txt.set_rotation(angle-90) for txt, angle 
             in zip(text, angles)]
        for ax in axes[1:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("off")
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
            grid = np.linspace(*ranges[i], 
                               num=n_ordinate_levels)
            gridlabel = ["{}".format(round(x,2)) 
                         for x in grid]
            if ranges[i][0] > ranges[i][1]:
                grid = grid[::-1] # hack to invert grid
                          # gridlabels aren't reversed
            gridlabel[0] = "" # clean up origin
            # ax.set_rgrids(grid, labels=gridlabel, angle=angles[i])
            set_rgrids(ax, grid, labels=gridlabel, angle=angles[i])
            #ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
            ax.set_ylim(*ranges[i])
        # variables for plotting
        self.angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[angles, angles[0]])
        self.ranges = ranges
        self.ax = axes[0]
    def plot(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.plot(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)
    def fill(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.fill(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)

# example data
variables = ("Normal Scale", "Inverted Scale", "Inverted 2", 
            "Normal Scale 2", "Normal 3", "Normal 4 %", "Inverted 3 %")
data = (-1.76, 1.1, 1.2, 
        4.4, 3.4, 86.8, 20)
ranges = [(-5, 3), (1.5, 0.3), (1.3, 0.5),
         (1.7, 4.5), (1.5, 3.7), (70, 87), (100, -50)]            
# plotting
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
radar = ComplexRadar(fig1, variables, ranges)
radar.plot(data)
radar.fill(data, alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

I can run everything up to the example data without any issues. But once I run the last 5 lines of code, Python loads but never stops loading. I'm struggling to see what's going wrong. Any help much appreciated!!

**UPDATE**

If I run `fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))`, I get this output:

```
`matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xe11a50`.
```

If I then try to show the figure (`fig1.show()`), this is the output:

```
UserWarning: matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure
```

How is the best way to get around this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. After a few seconds the radar plot is displayed on screen. Maybe you could look to see which line it is hanging on?

Comment: @tom I ran the first line (fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))) and got this output: <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x66ddeb0> rather than any sort of plot, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Either the default configuration doesn't support the display, or you don't have the environmental variable well set (this happens often when ssh for example). If it is the first reason, you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4930867/2237916.

Comment: @silgon looking at my matplotlibrc file, I am using TkAgg as my backend, which I believe is a GUI backend? Does this mean that the problem is more likely to be your second option ("you don't have the environmental variable well set"); in this case, how do I fix this?

Comment: Just try other environments, for example `matplotlib.use('Agg')`  just after importing matplotlib. I usually have to do that, but only when I'm using a server (or any computer through ssh) I use Agg, because it accepts just to save the image instead of showing it.