# plotting training data in keras outputs empty graph

Tags: python, keras, visualization

I am trying to plot the training data. I am using

```
for i in range(epoch_size):
    history = model.fit(trainingX[:10], trainingY[:10], epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size,callbacks = [early_stop], verbose=2)
```

in loop of 50

and then

```
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('acc')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

yet the plot is always empty, why is that?
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJrf1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the following `print(history.history)` and check the contents.

And we generally run its once.

```
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=128, epochs=10,
          verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

Comment: what if i need to run it in loop? I am rearanging input every epoch

Comment: Try to visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-can-i-set-the-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python/4930867?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). It might help you.

Comment: it does not help

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the history with each iteration of the for loop and for only one epoch there is no change that is possible to plot. So you either need more than one epoch or need to store the history values with a seperate array.