# matplotlib 'cairo.Context' error

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror, cairo

While running on my virtualenv I wrote this code on terminal and plot via matplotlib and shows me a 'Figure 1' named window with no drawing/content and throws 'TypeError' meanwhile:

```
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> x=[1,2,3,4]
>>> y=[2,4,6,8]
>>> plt.plot(x,y)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x6fd4ca10>]
>>> plt.show()
TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'cairo.Context'
TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'cairo.Context'
TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'cairo.Context'
TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'cairo.Context'
```

I'm using Stretch version of RaspBian. I had installed matplotlib with `sudo pip install matplotlib` and tried [this](https://github.com/thaines/helit/issues/8), also installed some dependent packages. What can I do?

Secondly are there any other way to draw histogram of image  in opencv without matplotlib library?

Comment: What is your backend set to? `plt.get_backend()` Would it be an option to change it, `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` and how does that change the error?

Comment: My backend is 'GTK3Agg'.
After applying 'TkAgg' it works(thank you so much!), but it is not permanent after reopening terminal. How can I make it permanent?

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294056/4124317).