# Setting figure size to be larger than screen size in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'm trying to create figures in `matplotlib` that read nicely in a journal article. I have some larger figures (with subfigures) that I'd like to take up nearly an entire page in portrait mode (specifically, 6.5"x9" for a full-page figure with 1" margins on US letter paper). I can set the figure size easily with the `figsize` parameter. However, the figure is compressed if I set the figure size to be larger than my screen size (I'm working on a 13" laptop); specifically, the height is an issue. The dimensions of the saved figure do not change as long as the `height` parameter below is larger than the height of my screen:

```
height = 9
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(6.5, height))
plt.savefig('test.png') # size of this figure is independent of height
                        # if height > height of my screen
```

How can I make `matplotlib` use the requested figure size even when it exceeds my screen's dimensions? I'm using spyder.

Comment: Might not be the ideal solution, but can you save as an SVG file, and then open in something like Inkscape and export as an appropriate quality PNG file?

Comment: @AndrewGuy just tried `height=9` and `height=10` with `test.svg` instead of `test.png` - the resulting files were identical.

Comment: What backend are you using? Run `import matplotlib; matplotlib.get_backend()`.

Comment: I'm using Qt5Agg

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue running the same code within a Jupyter notebook, so I suspect it is down to what backend you are using to draw the figure. Maybe try another backend?

Comment: For example, run `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')` at the start of your script.

Comment: That works, thanks @AndrewGuy!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer. :)

Comment: The problem is the use of spyder here. If you run the code as script from the CLI, it'll work as expected. Spyder turns on interactive mode by default and therefore the figure is "shown" before `savefig` is called. Upon showing, it is resized to match the screen. Using `agg` backend is one solution, because that cannot show anything. Turning off "matplotlib support" in the spyder options is another option. Also, possibly just adding `plt.ioff()` might work (not tested).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely an issue with your backend for plot generation.

You can see what backend you are using by running:

`import matplotlib; matplotlib.get_backend()`

Try changing the backend to something else, for example:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Note that this has to be run before importing `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Comment: Does not work for me. I get `UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()`

Comment: @Forklift17 Yes, this is expected behaviour if you are trying to show the plot inline rather than save to a file. See this question for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-can-i-set-the-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python

Comment: If I understand right, if I use figure size that does not fit into the computer screen there is no way whatsoever to see this figure on the screen with right proportions?