# Trying to set matplotlib window bigger than the screen, other posted solutions do not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys

print(sys.version)
print('Matplotlib version:', mpl.__version__)

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
ax.plot(np.cos(t), np.sin(t))

plt.show()
```

I am running this script on Spyder 4.0 and displaying on a small monitor. The frame just fills up the monitor and makes what should be a circle look like an ellipse.

The print statements give this output:

```
Python version: 3.7.6
Matplotlib version: 3.3.3
```

I want the frame as big as I want. I adapted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566198/setting-figure-size-to-be-larger-than-screen-size-in-matplotlib) solution and changed the import statements to:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import platform
```

The plot fails to show, with this message:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the backend to anything other than `Tkinter`, e.g. to Qt5:
[image]

Don't forget to restart the kernel for the change to take effect.

Comment: That didn't work. The window just does not want to expand past the screen size. I can't even manually expand it by moving it down and trying to drag-expand the window vertically.

Comment: It works for me (Arch Linux, openbox) for Qt5, Qt4, Gtk, Gtk3 but not for Tkinter, but the behavior appears to be OS/DE dependent, see [this matplotlib issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7338). See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622146/scrollbar-on-matplotlib-showing-page) for how to roll your own backend with scroll bars.